# How to read this JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Im sorry if this is a newbie question but I'm getting confuse about how to read this json string:

```
{
    "VF001JV018":[
      {
         "kode_question":"VF001JV018",
         "kode_option":1,
         "kode_option_tipe":"PF006",
         "nama_option":"Pilihan 1",
         "reference_db":null,
         "reference_table":null,
         "reference_field":null,
         "required_value":0,
         "reference_pk":null,
         "status":1
      },
      {
         "kode_question":"VF001JV018",
         "kode_option":4,
         "kode_option_tipe":"PF006",
         "nama_option":"Pilihan 4",
         "reference_db":null,
         "reference_table":null,
         "reference_field":null,
         "required_value":0,
         "reference_pk":null,
         "status":1
      },
      {
         "kode_question":"VF001JV018",
         "kode_option":5,
         "kode_option_tipe":"PF006",
         "nama_option":"Lainnya",
         "reference_db":null,
         "reference_table":null,
         "reference_field":null,
         "required_value":1,
         "reference_pk":null,
         "status":1
      }
   ],
   "VF001JV020":[
      {
         "kode_question":"VF001JV020",
         "kode_option":1,
         "kode_option_tipe":"PF001",
         "nama_option":"Kode Toko",
         "reference_db":"crm",
         "reference_table":"customer",
         "reference_field":"kode_customer",
         "required_value":0,
         "reference_pk":"          ",
         "status":1
      }
   ]
}
```

How to show the data in list? for example:

```
<ul>
<li><strong>VF001JV018</strong></li>
<li>VF001JV018-1</li>
<li>VF001JV018-4</li>
<li>VF001JV018-5</li>
<li><strong>VF001JV020</strong></li>
<li>VF001JV020-1</li>
</ul>
```

I use jquery each function to loop each element but still no luck

```
$.getJSON('data.json', null, function(response){
    var echo = '<ul>';
    $(response).each(function(k,v){
        echo += '<li><strong>'+k+'</strong> : '+v+'</li>';
    });
    echo += '</ul>';
    $('#here').html(echo);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response` is not a HTML string or DOM element. You cannot pass it to jQuery this way.

Use [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to loop over it:

```
$.each(response, function(k, v) {
    echo += '<li><strong>'+k+'</strong></li>';
});
```

You cannot concatenate the string with `v`, as `v` is an array again. You have to loop over it and access the specific information you want to print, e.g. `v[i].status`.

Comment: thanks for the solution, it works. I have one more problem. The v is an object. I access it using v[0].status because there are many object in v. Should I use the each again? If I use the jQuery.each again, is there any problem will occur because it is loop inside loop

Comment: @Permana: Oh you are right, I missed that it is an array (updated my post). No, you can use it again. You can also use a normal for loop, it is up to you.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I will use the jQuery.each again. Im asking is it going to be error if I use loop inside loop because previously I'm getting error when doing Ajax request inside loop. Thanks again.